# Plot Lognormal Probability Density in R

Tags: r, plot, probability-density

I am trying to generate a plot for Lognormal Probability Density in R, with 3 different means log and standards deviation log. I have tried the following, but my graph is so ugly and does not look good at all.

```
 x<- seq(0,10,length = 100)
 a <- dlnorm(x, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1, log = FALSE)
 b <- dlnorm(x, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1.5, log = FALSE)
 g <- dlnorm(x, meanlog = 1.5, sdlog = 0.2, log = FALSE)
 plot(x,a, lty=5, col="blue", lwd=3)
 lines(x,b, lty=2, col = "red")
 lines(x,g, lty=4, col = "green")
```

I even was trying to add legend on the right top for each mean log and standard deviation log, but it would not work with me. I was wondering if someone could guide me out with that.

[Right top of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNTVw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really nothing wrong in your code. You just forgot to:

- use `type = "l"` in `plot`;
- set a good `ylim` to hold all lines.

Here is a simple solution with `matplot`:

```
matplot(x, cbind(a,b,g), type = "l", ylab = "density", main = "log-normal",
        col = 1:3, lty = 1:3)
```

To add legend, use

```
legend("topright",
       legend = c("mu = 0, sd = 1", "mu = 0, sd = 1.5", "mu = 1.5, sd = 0.2"),
       col = 1:3,
       lty = 1:3)
```

[image]

You can also read `?plotmath` for adding expressions. Try changing the `legend` argument above to:

```
legend = c(expression(ln(y) %~% N(0,1)),
           expression(ln(y) %~% N(0,1.5)),
           expression(ln(y) %~% N(1.5,0.2)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I come up with something like this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNTVw.png on the top right of the graph

Comment: Thank you so much!!