# how do I create a probability plot in R using R-studio

Tags: r, probability

I want to create a lognormal (or other distribution) probability plot in R (for R-studio).  I have looked around on the web for an example but none of the examples tell me what package I need to install in order to use the function.

```
logn_prob_plot <- function() 
{ 

    x<-rlnorm(10,5,1) 
    x 
    probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm,xlab="failure time",ylab="lognormal probability") 

}


Error in probplot(x, qdist = qlnorm, xlab = "failure time", ylab = "lognormal probability") : could not find function "probplot"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "probability plot"- maybe a probability density function? If so there are already [some SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527932/plot-lognormal-probability-density-in-r) on that subject.

Comment: It sounds like you searched and found some examples, but weren't sure how to run them. Could you add a link or code snippet to your post? Right now it's hard to tell what package you might be trying to use.

Comment: A probability plot is a plot of the cdf, not density.  It adjusts the y-axis so that the points will fall on a straight line.  

I have a snippet of code and the result.  I found that there is a function called "probplot" but I don't know what package it is in so I don't know what I need to install.

Comment: logn_prob_plot <- function() 
{
  x<-rlnorm(10,5,1)

  x

  probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm,xlab="failure time",ylab="lognormal probability")
}

Comment: probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm,xlab="failure time",ylab="lognormal probability")

Error in probplot(x, qdist = qlnorm, xlab = "failure time", ylab = "lognormal probability") : 
  could not find function "probplot"

Comment: Googling "r probplot" got me the documentation for the function in `e1071`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-1/topics/probplot. Please [edit] your question to include the code you have in comments so it can be formatted properly and more easily read

Comment: Thanks camille.  I tried that but it gave me the same error that it couldn't find the function probplot.  What package do I need to install to use the function probplot?

Also, I am new to this and I have to learn how to edit my comments.  Thanks for being patient.  :)

Comment: So it sounds like you want to install the `e1071` package, which is available [in CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html). You can do this using `install.packages("e1071")` in your terminal or by selecting `Tools -> Install Packages` in the RStudio GUI. You can then load that package using `library("e1071")`. (That's just an answer about how to install a package, though, not how to make a plot. If you click on [the edit link camille shared](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56387315/edit) you will be taken to a page where you can add plotting code to your question.)

Comment: thanks Alexanian!  I have tried that and it works.  I can now make probability plots.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Writing up the comment thread as an answer:

The error (`could not find function "probplot"`) is showing up because a necessary package is not installed. It's not specifically related to creating a probability plot.

Googling "r probplot" turns up [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-1/topics/probplot) for the package `e1071`, which is available [in CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/index.html).

The package can be installed by entering `install.packages("e1071")` in your terminal or by selecting `Tools -> Install Packages` in the RStudio GUI. You can then load that package using `library("e1071")`.